# Is $A\cong \operatorname{hom}(A,\Bbb Z) \oplus \operatorname{Ext}(A,\Bbb Z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be any abelian group. Is $A\cong \operatorname{hom}(A,\Bbb Z) \oplus \operatorname{Ext}(A,\Bbb Z)$ ?

For finitely generated $A$ this is clear from the structure theorem but I am not sure about the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ and apply $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\mathbb{Z})$ to get
$$
0\to
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\to
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})\to
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\to
\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\to
\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})\to
\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\to0
$$
Since $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=0$, we infer that $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ is not torsion, because it contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.